# Using "on" as a time measurement unit

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

The example: There were no cars on(during) Tutankhamon's time.

Is the word "on" used correctly in the example above? If not, why?

Comment: is "during" supposed to replace "on" or do you think both should be used together? what do you think is correct?

Comment: I used "during" as an alternative to "on".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. We generally only use ***on*** for time to refer to days.

> I'm going to the mall **on Friday**.
>   You don't make a fuss of me like that **on *my* birthday**.

To refer to smaller units of time, we might use *at* for a specific point in time:

> I'll get home **at three o'clock**.

Or *during* for periods of time:

> I'll be working **during the afternoon**.

And for longer periods of time, it would be **in**:

> There were no cars **in Tutankhamun's time**.
>   **In 2100**, will we still travel for work?

Though you can still use **during** for longer periods of time as well.